# eb logs display binary data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed an application using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and I am using the EB CLI to access my logs.

Until recently when I did `eb logs` I was able to tail my logs. But now when I issue the same command, `eb` prints some binary data, for example:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log-20150906.gz
-------------------------------------
^_<8B>^H^@<90><A5><EB>U^@^C<ED><9D><DF>s<E3><C8>q<C7><DF><F3>W<A8>
.......
```

As you can see the log file is gzipped. How can I make `eb` return the logs as text so I can read them?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `eb logs --all` as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html#ebcli3-basics-logs). This will save the logs to a directory.

Comment: This works, but I want to view the logs in the console, I want to avoid dealing with the zip file if possible.

Comment: I think for now you will have to pipe the saved logs through gzip command line utility

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by elasticbeanstalk default configuration.
At least in `64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)` platform.

If you login to your instance with `eb ssh` and run `cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/nginx.conf`
You'll find out that by default `eb logs` tails every file in `/var/log/nginx/` directory.

So we need to change `/var/log/nginx/*` to `/var/log/nginx/*.log`

It can be done by creating `.ebextensions/0001_eb_logs.config` file in root directory of your project.
File's content:

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/nginx.conf" :
      mode: "000644"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        /var/log/nginx/*.log

commands:
    rm_old_conf:
      command: "rm nginx.conf.bak"
      cwd: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/"
      ignoreErrors: true
```